# DuckDB: ST_GeometryType(BLOB) add explicit type casts

Tags: sql, duckdb

I'm trying to return the different Geometry types from a bunch of parquet files

I get this error each time

```
Error: Binder Error: No function matches the given name and argument types 'ST_GeometryType(BLOB)'. You might need to add explicit type casts.
    Candidate functions:
    ST_GeometryType(POINT_2D) -> ANY
    ST_GeometryType(LINESTRING_2D) -> ANY
    ST_GeometryType(POLYGON_2D) -> ANY
    ST_GeometryType(GEOMETRY) -> ANY

LINE 1: SELECT DISTINCT ST_GeometryType(geometry) FROM ......
```

I've tried several alternatives

At windows CMD prompt CD to Directory containing exe and type duckdb.exe this starts in memory session you then need to load extensions

```
SET extension_directory TO 'PathTo\\duckdb_cli-windows-amd64\\extensions';
LOAD spatial;
LOAD parquet;
```

This returns as expected so I know the extensions have loaded

```
SELECT DISTINCT ST_ASText(geometry) AS geom FROM 'PathTo\\*.parquet' LIMIT 5;
```

The [DuckDB Docs](https://duckdb.org/docs/archive/0.8.1/extensions/spatial.html) state GeometryType ST_GeometryType(GEOMETRY)

> - DuckDB - functions that are implemented natively in this extension that are capable of operating directly on the DuckDB type

These are some of the various attempts I've made all return the same error

```
SELECT DISTINCT ST_GeometryType(geometry)  AS geom_type FROM 'PathTo\\*.parquet';
SELECT DISTINCT ST_ASText(geometry) AS geom_type FROM 'PathTo\\*.parquet';
SELECT DISTINCT ST_GeometryType(geometry)::TEXT AS geom_type FROM 'PathTo\\*.parquet';
```

Hoping someone can explain what I'm doing wrong

Incidentally in PostgreSQL / PostGIS `SELECT DISTINCT GeometryType(geometry) FROM MyGeoTable;` returns POINT, LINE etc. This is wat I need from the DuckDB query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parquet has no concept of a "geometry" type, so geometry data is usually (e.g. in the GeoParquet spec) encoded as binary blobs (what DuckDB interprets as the `BLOB` type). So when you import from the parquet file you end up with a `BLOB` column, which DuckDB does not consider to be the same as `GEOMETRY`, which is why you get the error:
`Error: Binder Error: No function matches the given name and argument types 'ST_GeometryType(BLOB)'.` DuckDB does currently not support the reading the special metadata present in GeoParquet files so it does not identify geometry columns as containing GEOMETRY.

Since `ST_GeometryType` is not defined for `BLOB`, the solution is to call a conversion function that decodes whatever binary geometry encoding is in the `BLOB` into a `GEOMETRY`.

Since I don't know how you got the parquet files I don't know how the geometry is encoded, but my guess is that if the files are "GeoParquet" it is probably encoded as [Well Known Binary](https://libgeos.org/specifications/wkb/). You can then use the `ST_GeomFromWKB(BLOB) -> GEOMETRY` function to attempt to decode the blobs to geometry.

The following query should work:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ST_GeometryType(ST_GeomFromWKB(geometry)) AS geom_type FROM 'PathTo\\*.parquet' LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: Yes allegedly Geoparquet from overture maps (Nov 23 version) geometry is WKB  your solution works Thank you for the explanation